# How to pass data from onItemClick to a TextView in another method?

Tags: android, onclick, textview

I'm using an SQLite database to populate a listview. I've made it so that the user can not pass the data to the listview until a TextView has been populated.

Now I'm trying to get the TextView, which is defined in XML, to be populated by having the user click a button that should then display text on the TextView. However, I do not know how I can pass it to the TextView when it's not made programmatically.

So how can I pass the data (packageName) to TextView?

If relevant, my onItemClick looks like this:

```
myGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

            // Putting package name into packageName
            final String packageName = mApps.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;
            ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
            info.activityInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked " + packageName,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: then whats wrong, you didnt say whats not working and the errors you get

Comment: I just do not know how to pass it from onItemClick to a TextView that is not made programmatically. Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: you want text-view's text? or anything else

Comment: Where is TextView? Is in each row of ListView?

Comment: mTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pName); However user3241226 gave me the (obvious) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do need to declare your text view then put this inside the OnItemClick method.

```
myTextView.setText(packageName);
```

Comment: It... really was that simple? Thank you, user3241226! I should have known, but spending 26 hours learning SQLite just for a concept app has killed me. This worked wonderfully.

Comment: Yes SQlite is a pain to learn I have written a simple IO class if you are interested for future concepts http://androidjavaio.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/a-simple-android-java-io-class-using.html

Comment: Bookmarked! If you don't mind, I'd like to query you about something. Now that the user can see his selection in the ListView, do you know how I can then start an intent with the that text? It is stored in CONTENT_PKG, but this ( http://pastebin.com/KgctSXtM ) did not work.

Comment: Im not sure on that one but I believe you should be using myIntent.putExtra("ID", String); instead of getStringExtra. The same may apply for addCategory too